# Magento 2: Override checkout/onepage template of Luma theme

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have created a custom theme, let say `Namespace/customtheme` based on `Magento/Luma` theme and copied `onepage.phtml` template of `Magento_Checkout` module in custom theme.

After overriding `onepage.phtml`, checkout page is not working properly. `Block Loader (Magento_Ui/js/block-loader)` of checkout page is always showing even the page has been loaded completely.

If I remove the onepage.phtml file from custom theme the it works well.

I have tried to deploy the static content but no luck.

Here is the content of overridden onepage.phtml template:

> app/design/frontend/Namespace/customtheme/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<div id="checkout" data-bind="scope:'checkout'" class="checkout-container">
    <div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask">
    <div class="loader">
        <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
             alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Loading...'); ?>"
             style="position: absolute;">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#checkout": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    window.checkoutConfig = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getCheckoutConfig()); ?>;
    // Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
    window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
    window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
</script>
<script>
    require([
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
    ], function(url, blockLoader) {
        blockLoader("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>");
        return url.setBaseUrl('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>');
    })
</script>
</div>
```

> Checkout Page

[image: M2 Checkout Screenshot]

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: There are any errors on your browser console?

Comment: There is no error on browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is caused due to the missing "checkoutLoader" configuration.

Try to add the following code:

```
data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'
```

at the end of the div with the `id="checkout-loader"`.

```
<div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
```