# Magento 2 checkout loader not hide in Internet Explorer

Tags: magento2, checkout

If JavaScript Bundling is Enabled checkout loader (loader layer) never hide (loader keeps loading) only in Internet Explorer and Safari. If I turn off JS Bundling all works

No errors in console

Who had this issue ?

I use magento 2.1.11

[this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147981/magento-2-checkout-loader-keeps-loading) does not help

Answer (score 0):

Try this stuck checkout loader:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13398