# Magento 2: How to add additional block on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, blocks, custom, magento-2.1.3

I would like to override the below file & display my custom block in the `li`.

**magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html**

```
<li id="shipping" class="checkout-shipping-address" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Address'" data-role="title"></div>
</li>   

<!-- ko if:myBlock --> // Mine need to call block created from Admin
<li>
    <p data-bind="html: myBlock"></p>
</li> 
<!-- /ko -->

<!--Shipping method template-->
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
    class="checkout-shipping-method"
    data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
    role="presentation">
    <div class="checkout-shipping-method">
        <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Methods'" data-role="title"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

If the block is enabled in the admin then it will show a custom `li` with the block data, otherwise it shows nothing.

Can we check directly in the `.html` file whether the block is enabled or not?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142680/how-to-call-static-block-in-knockout-template-file

Comment: Hi @AlexConstantinescu Would like to display above Shipping Method

Answer (score 28):

Here I give example to **show custom block above shipping method** of checkout

1. Create **di.xml** at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cms_block_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

2. Create **ConfigProvider.php** to define your static block to **windows.checkoutConfig**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /** @var LayoutInterface  */
    protected $_layout;

    public function __construct(LayoutInterface $layout)
    {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $myBlockId = "my_static_block"; // CMS Block Identifier
        //$myBlockId = 20; // CMS Block ID

        return [
            'my_block_content' => $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($myBlockId)->toHtml()
        ];
    }
}
```

3. Override checkout_index_index.xml in your module and define your own shipping component

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="shipping_custom_block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/shipping/customblock</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

4. Now create **shipping.js** and define your own shipping template file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping/customblock.js

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'jquery',
        'ko'
    ],
    function(
        Component,
        $,
        ko
    ) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_Module/shipping/customblock'
            },

            initialize: function () {
                var self = this;
                this._super();
            }

        });
    }
);
```

5. Create **customblock.html**

`<div data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.my_block_content"></div>`

Here I add new product widget in my static block

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: i have did the same but not working. i cant see static block content at this tab.

Comment: @Prince, what should I do to display block below "Shipping methods"?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari place your block div at the last in `shipping.html` to show block after shipping method

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I'm trying to copy shipping.html in my theme `Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html`, then changes are not reflecting on frontend, I executed deply command as well.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari It must be browser cache. Check this answer for diffrent way to check changes of knockout js and html files: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/227290/35758

Comment: Yeah! it was browser cache, thanks for your help.

Comment: can somone confirm if it's working for Magento 2.2.4 version

Comment: its not working

Comment: Where did you get before-shipping-method-form from? What if I would like to put it after the total?

Comment: Can we add this before Shipping Method title or After the Phone Number?

Comment: Show block after shipping-methods: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92740/1883

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did to display a CMS block on checkout page under sidebar. 1. In the templates/onepage.phtml I created a js variable to hold the cms block content like this:

```
<?php $myCmsBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('my_cms_block')->toHtml() ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_cms_block = <?php echo json_encode($myCmsBlock)?>;
</script>
```

2. In the knockout template file (in my case it was web/js/template/sidebar.html), displayed the cms block content from the above js variable like this:

```
<div class="opc-help-cms" data-bind="html:my_cms_block">
    </div>
```

Hope this helps someone! Thanks!

Comment: Simple solution. Just needed to prepare custom onepage.phtml. I used this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127150/magento-2-override-checkout-onepage-template-of-luma-theme

Comment: do you know what should i do if i want to add it to payment step? i tried to add what you mentioned above to vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html and payment.html but doesn't make any effect.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296500/how-to-add-texts-to-payment-step-onepage-checkout-page

Comment: payment.html should be able to access the js variable from onepage.phtml. Make sure its rendered properly by printing it on console in checkout page

Answer (score 0):

Create **di.xml** at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cms_block_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\CustomConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\CustomConfigProvider">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="blockId" xsi:type="string">my_static_block</argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
    
</config>
```

Now Create **CustomConfigProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class CustomConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /** @var LayoutInterface  */
    protected $_layout;

    public function __construct(LayoutInterface $layout, $blockId)
    {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
        $this->cmsBlock = $this->constructBlock($blockId);
    }

    public function constructBlock($blockId)
    {
        $block = $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($blockId)->toHtml();
        return $block;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'my_block_content' => $this->cmsBlock
        ];
    }
}
```

> Because the variable has been added to the global window.checkoutConfig variable, now you can use window.checkoutConfig.cms_block variable to call that content.

Now create **shipping.js** and define your own shipping template file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping/customblock.js

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'jquery',
        'ko'
    ],
    function(
        Component,
        $,
        ko
    ) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_Module/shipping/customblock'
            },

            initialize: function () {
                var self = this;
                this._super();
            }

        });
    }
);
```

Create **customblock.html**

```
<div data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.my_block_content"></div>
```

Override **checkout_index_index.xml** in your module

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="shipping_custom_block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/shipping/customblock</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

---

**IMPORTANT :-**

> My answer is almost same as [Prince's Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176327/93504). just I declared `CMS Block Identifier` in **frontend/di.xml** instead of write it in `CustomConfigProvider`. I passed CMS Block Identifier using di.xml instead of hard coded in CustomConfigProvider.php file

Comment: for refenece https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-cms-block-checkout-page-magento-2.html#step-1

Answer (score -3):

add static block in phtml fie :

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

add block using XML :

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
       <arguments>
         <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument>
       </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

add block in cms page :

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```