# Magento 2. How to add new text field in block ''ship to' in check out?

Tags: checkout, shipping, onepage-checkout, magento-2.2.1, checkout-page

I need to add some text by programmatically in 'ship to' in check out step in magento 2.2.1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot use static blocks or phtml files directly in html.** For that you need to inject a static block in windows.checkoutConfig object with use of `configProviders` in Magento 2.

**1) Create di.xml at**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cms_block_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2) Create ConfigProvider.php to define your static block to windows.checkoutConfig**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /** @var LayoutInterface  */
    protected $_layout;

    public function __construct(LayoutInterface $layout)
    {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $myBlockId = "my_static_block"; // CMS Block Identifier
        //$myBlockId = 20; // CMS Block ID

        return [
            'my_block_content' => $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($myBlockId)->toHtml()
        ];
    }
}
```

**3) Now override `shipping-information.html` in your theme**

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-information.html

And copy this code

```
<div data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.my_block_content"></div>
```

Check this answer for more details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176327/35758

Answer (score 0):

You could copy and edit this template file:

```
Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-information.html
```

If you want to edit anything in the address itself you need this file:

```
Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html
```

Comment: How to add the block to this file? Sanne