# How to add texts to payment step Onepage checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, phtml

Which file should i edit to add text underneath all the payment methods. ( I would like to add some return/refund policy).

The URL is

> https://www.mywebsite.com/checkout/#payment

[image]

Comment: The way I got it to work was as follows: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/357524/how-to-add-simple-text-to-payment-step-onepage-checkout-page/357573#357573

Comment: The way I got it to work was as follows:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/357524/how-to-add-simple-text-to-payment-step-onepage-checkout-page/357573#357573

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to follow below steps, by following these steps you can add your `phtml` files changes on checkout page's payment step after discount code.

Create `di.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="return_refund_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now you need to crate `ConfigProvider.php` Model file here on this path in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ConfigProvider.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    protected $_layout;

    public function __construct(LayoutInterface $layout)
    {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'return_refund_policy' => $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::return_refund_policy.phtml")->toHtml()
        ];
    }
}
```

- Here in above file we have added one key `return_refund_policy` in `getConfig()` function so we can access this using `window.checkoutConfig.return_refund_policy` on checkout page's `html` file, and we set our template path (phtml template) to that array key.

Now we will create `phtml` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/return_refund_policy.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<?php echo "This is return and Refund Policy sample text!!!!"; ?>
```

- I've added sample text here, you can add whatever you want here to display.

Now we will create `checkout_index_index.xml` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="return-refund-policy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/payment/return-refund-policy</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

- Here in this file I've added on `JS` file called `return-refund-policy.js` after payment method section on checkout page.

So now we will create on `JS` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/return-refund-policy.js

Content for this file is..

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'jquery',
], function (Component, ko, $) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_Module/return-refund-policy'
            },

            initialize: function () {
                var self = this;
                this._super();
            }

        });
    }
);
```

- Here in this file I've added `html` template path which is `return-refund-policy.html`.

So now we will create `html` file here in our custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/return-refund-policy.html

Content for this file is

```
<div data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.return_refund_policy"></div>
```

That's it. Now we need to run below command once

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

[image: Checkout Custom Block on Payment step Magento 2]

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Thanks, Kishan!  This solution works, too. I made another solution that takes the content from cms block, so other user can make the changes from the admin panel.

Comment: On one of the two site, the return/refund policy message shows before the "apply discount code' area, do you know how to fix that? I already set the module to load after Magento_Checkout on app/etc/config.php, also set the <sequence><module name="Magento_Checkout"/></sequence> on module.xml. Thanks.

Comment: never mind.. figured out, put it after <sequence><module name="Magento_SalesRule"/></sequence> works.

Comment: thanks again for your help!

Comment: Still works perfectly on Magento 2.4.5. This should be Magento official doc page.