# How to add simple text to payment step Onepage checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, phtml

Which file should i edit to add text underneath all the payment methods.
Magento ver. 2.4.2-p1
http://mydev.test/checkout/#payment

this Answer not work for me: [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296500/how-to-add-texts-to-payment-step-onepage-checkout-page)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to add it in the following way.

```
1. Identify which template displays the information: /my_project/vendor/magento/module-gift-card-account/view/frontend/web/template/payment/gift-card-account.html

2. Add to my theme since in my case it didn't exist: /app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_GiftCardAccount/web/template/payment/gift-card-account.html
```

Add the necessary text and it works